# Why is my C program crashing after input?

Tags: crash, crash-reports

I am learning to program in C and C++.
My C program keeps crashing after input, here's the code:

```
\#include\<stdio.h\>
main(){
int n, i,a,sum=0;
printf("How many numbers?\\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=0;i\<n;i++){
printf("What's the %d number\\n", i+1);
scanf("%d", &a);
sum=sum+a;
}
printf("Sum is %d", sum);
}
```

And here's the output from my compile log

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  gcc.exe...
gcc.exe "C:\\Dev-Cpp\\Reee.c" -o "C:\\Dev-Cpp\\Reee.exe"    -I"C:\\Dev-Cpp\\include"   -L"C:\\Dev-Cpp\\lib"
Execution terminated
Compilation successful

There is 0 errors and 0 warnings.
```

If someone knows how to fix it I would be really thankful.

I tried to make a program that sums up all the numbers in a row. I expected a sum output but the program crashed after input. The program crashes after I input the last number in a row, where it should sum up all of them and output the sum.

Comment: When you say "crashes" what exactly do you mean? Does it show an error? Gets stuck? Blue screen?

Comment: The program window closes and the Dev C++ app freezes.

Comment: So the program just ends. That's not a crash, you just don't have anything in the program to stop it from ending. Put another scanf at the end so that you have time to read the output before the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

I copied this program, added "void" to the main function
and changed the include statement like this ⬇️
everything worked just fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n, i, a, sum = 0;
    printf("How many numbers?\\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("What's the %d number\\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a);
        sum = sum + a;
    }
    printf("Sum is %d", sum);
}
//output:
How many numbers?\n2
What's the 1 number\n4
What's the 2 number\n5
Sum is 9
```

you should use only one \ when you print somthing.

Comment: I used one \  I guess the site changed it. Your program is also crashing on my PC after the input. I think it's a bug, I uninstalled my C++ and installed it again but it just doesn't work.

Comment: maybe you should install C (I'm new to C but I know there is some differances between C and C++)